# error while sending data from view to controller via $ ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am sending data from view to controller via jquery ajax call but this giving error dialog box i dont know what exactly the error is.here is my code.
Please help me.i tried the alernative which is commented,also tried this

Code:

```
          data:{'startValue' : startValue,'endValue':endValue },
          data:{"startValue" : startValue,"endValue":endValue },
```

none of them is working.

Booking Model:

```
     public class Booking
      {

    public string reservationId { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Start date")]
    public string endDate { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select end date")]
    public string startHour { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select Start time")]
    public string endHour { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select end time")]
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string vehicleId { get; set; }
    public string spaceId { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
       <script type="text/JavaScript">
        function sendVales() {
        var startValue = $('#startDate').val();
        var endValue = $('#endDate').val();
        alert(startValue + "" + endValue);

        var dataRequested = { startDate: startValue, endDate: endValue };
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            url: '@Url.Action("makeReservation", "Booking")',
          //  data:{startValue : startValue,endValue:endValue },
            data: JSON.stringify(dataRequested),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success, sent data to controller");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error: " + data.responseText);
                }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Controller

```
       [HttpPost]

        public JsonResult makeReservation(Booking bookModel)
        {    bool success = false;
        try
        {
            success = bookingObj.addBooking(userName, bookModel);
            if (success)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Space has been booked.");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Space can be reserved.Correct the errors and try aggain");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex);
        }
             return Json(new { success }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
```

Comment: On alert box there is srting error : 
dont know the error

Comment: what is your Booking class definition?

Comment: see that.i have udated my code

Comment: `data:{'startValue' : startValue,'endValue':endValue },
          data:{"startValue" : startValue,"endValue":endValue },` doesn't look like a `Booking` class

Comment: also, why do you have a trailing comma?

Comment: how i send these values to controller,when i get two strings in controller like string start,string end it is again null.please modify the code for my understanding or give me some logic